# How to avoid insecure websockets requests in Apache Httpd?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, websocket

I have an Apache server in front of a Websocket Tomcat server, and I would like to restrict access to secure websockets only (wss://).

How can I achieve that in Apache configuration ?

One thing that I do not understand is that even if I block port 80 (not 443) on AWS, it is still possible for me to connect to my unsecured ws via Simple WebSocket Client, whereas a `telnet myHost 80` is logically failing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, configuring Apache with SSL is enough : it will redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

I did not figure out that quickly, but I can only connect with WS protocol only after I have been redirected by the browser with a simple HTTP request to HTTPS. And then, when I try to connect with WS, looking at Chrome Developer tools, I can see in request headers that the final endpoint is WSS.

So, in Simple WebSocket Client, I am actually silently redirected to WSS endpoint when trying to connect with insecure WS. As I said previously, this silent redirection is enabled only after a HTTP to HTTPS redirection on a simple call in the browser. You can check it by closing your browser and trying to reconnect in WS via Simple WebSocket Client : you will get a 403 HTTP error.